# Navigating through UIVIewControllers

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

From the `FirstView` to the `SecondView` i will be navigating through `pushViewController`.

In the `SecondView` there's a button, when i click that i will be calling another view which is called `ThirdView`, and i will be navigating through `presentModalViewController animated:YES`.

I need a code, to go from the `ThirdViewController` to `FirstViewController`, How can i do that ?

I have not tried any code, because i am clueless as what to do

Comment: See my answer on the above linked question, it is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use delegate to move back to the first view controller... On cancel button in the THIRD, delegate some method to the SECOND, where you:

1) [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

and

2) [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

FIRST would be active as a result

Comment: Can you show me a code example to do this ? please note that from view 1 --> view 2 (I am using pushviewcontroller), and from view2 --- view3  (i am using presentmodalviewcontroller)

Comment: I am not on MAC now to write the whole code , but i will try

Comment: The thing is that, i am not using navigationView controller in the 2nd and 3rd view.

Comment: If the first viewcontroller is in the navigation you do not need to create more.

Comment: As far as i understood, first dismiss the modal view controller and then pop viewcontroller. these two events should fired in sequence i guess. just try that. because you have to have dismiss the modal view controller any how.

Answer (score 1):

I flagged as a duplicate but you are getting a lot of misleading answers here, so I'll re-post my answer from the other question:

`popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` on UINavigationController will clear out the stack and return you to the root controller. There is no need to individually dismiss each controller in the stack.

Answer (score 1):

In your second view controller add method like

```
-(void)goToFirstViewController{
      [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
 }
```

In third View controller

```
UIViewController *secondVC = [self parentViewController];

// If you use ios 5 do [[self presentingViewController] popViewController];

[secondVC goToFirstViewController];

[self dismissModalViewController];
```